Asymptote: white gaps in surface
In a question and answer of mine, I provided some Asymptote code which compiled nicely.
Now, compiling the same code, I get a different output.
Here the code repeated, identical to the old answer:
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
    settings.prc = false;
    settings.render = 0;
    unitsize(1cm);
    fontsize(11pt);
    size(5cm);

    import graph3;
    import palette;

    currentprojection=orthographic(-0.8,-1.1,0.8);
    int angles = 60;
    int radii = 15;

    triple f(pair z) { // using polar coordinates
        return (z.x * cos(z.y), z.x * sin(z.y), sqrt(z.x) * cos(z.y/2));
    }

    triple c(pair z) { // using polar coordinates
        return (z.x * cos(z.y), z.x * sin(z.y), sqrt(z.x) * sin(z.y/2));
    }

    surface s = surface(f, (0,-pi), (1,3pi), nu=radii, nv=angles, Spline);
    pen[][] p = palette(surface(c, (0,-pi), (1,3pi), nu=radii, nv=angles).map(zpart), Wheel());
    draw(s, mean(p), meshpen=black+linewidth(0.2pt));

    xaxis3(Bounds(Min, Min), -1, 1, OutTicks(2,2));
    yaxis3(Bounds(Min, Min), -1, 1, OutTicks(2,2));
    zaxis3(Bounds(Min, Max), -1, 1, OutTicks(2,2));
\end{asy}

\end{document}

This is the new output:

As you can see, there are a lot of white gaps in the surface, which were not there in the old answer.
I don't recall the old Asymptote version I used to compile it.
How can I fix this with the current Asymptote version? I have Asymptote version 2.89git.

the code works well in http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/  (without settings.prc = false;     settings.render = 0;) . "White gaps" maybe is a problem of your laptop

@BlackMild True. But I noticed that the Asymptote version on this website is 2.88, and I'm using the most recent 2.89. So is this just a bug?
